# Read one item from MSQ as a string in php

Tags: php, sql

I have:

```
$thisauthor = $db->get_results("SELECT author FROM history WHERE RefID=11");
```

and I became the result as an array.

How could i take it as a string?

Comment: Is this a Wordpress-specific question? Please add the relevant tags.

Answer (score 0):

You get it as an array of all columns, that means array containing one element, `author`. The way that would work will be then calling it as

```
$thisauthor["author"]
```

or to get just the string:

```
$thisauthor = $db->get_results("SELECT author FROM history WHERE RefID=11")["author"];
```

or just get the variable

```
$thisauthor = $db->get_var("SELECT author FROM history WHERE RefID=11");
```